# How to declare a int to be specific value/number

Tags: java, int, boolean

For example, i am writing a program that takes textinput, and converts it to int. I want the input of the number to be less than or equal to 5, but greater than or equal to 0 (0<=number<=5), how would i write this?

```
   int number;
   textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number");
   number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
```

I want the user to enter a number between 0 and 5, if they enter any other number a message says the number is not valid and they enter it again

EDIT: thanks for the answers, i used the do while loop and it works, I just want to ask now, how would i make a box popup saying : "Error: please enter a number between 0 and 5", then showing the input box again.

Thanks

Comment: Use a `while` loop to continuously check the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [do-while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop:

```
int number;
do {
    String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
    number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
} while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5));
```

**EDIT**: if you want to show an error message, try:

```
String textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("give me a number between 0 and 5");
int number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 5)) {
    textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("error: please a number between 0 and 5");
    number = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
}
```

Comment: lol, why do the votes on this answer keep going up and down and up and down? :P

Comment: Someone is still hesitating, I guess :P

Comment: thanks for the answers, i used the do while loop and it works, I just want to ask now, how would i make a box popup saying : "Error: please enter a number between 0 and 5", then showing the input box again.

Comment: where would i add the joptionpane exactly? sorry if this sounds stupid, im really new to java

Comment: @Donnie you would move the first message out of the loop, then put your new message in a `while` loop. I'll edit my answer when I get to a computer (commenting from my phone right now)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Untitled{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int in = -1;
        while( in < 0 || in > 5){
            String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter number");
            in = Integer.parseInt(m);
            if(in < 0 || in > 5){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"enter again");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `while` condition is incorrect. That's going to loop until the user enters an *incorrect* value, at which point it will print "enter again" but exit the loop.

Comment: Your loop is infinite for legal values.

Comment: (also, this doens't even compile)

Comment: this still doesn't compile. your syntax is wrong. also, you never initialize `in` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done, with a single line of code, if your aim is to block user from giving wrong inputs.

Use the format below

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parentComponent, message, title, messageType, icon, selectionValues, initialSelectionValue)
```

this will give a predefined set of values to be selected. For Eg.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "test", "test", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Integer[]{0,1,2,3,4,5}, 0);
```

would produce some output like this

[image]

But if you need to do it with validations, and throw some errors, you can follow the methods like above.